# How to enable aufs support on raspberry Pi, specifically, raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, filesystem, storage

I have installed raspbian (and 2 other distro's) on an 8G Class 10 card in my raspberry Pi 2 and I am running out of space on root filesystem after adding a few applications. I understand from [debian reference](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch09.en.html#_expansion_of_usable_storage_space_using_aufs) that I maybe able to add space into an existing directory using [aufs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufs) and I am thinking if this could be the solution.

According to the [Aufs homepage](http://aufs.sourceforge.net/) the kernel version on my pi (3.18.16+...) is supported, however `aptitude search aufs` returns no results. Based on the info in the debian reference I was looking for aufs-tools  or kernel modules to show up.

I am thinking support is not available by default since `/sbin/mount.aufs` is not present and `man aufs` does not find anything  - maybe I am wrong.

**Any idea on how I can enable aufs support on raspbian ?**

By the way, if at all this works, I intend to mount /usr from a USB disk and leave the rest of the root file system intact.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be troubles including [aufs support in main line kernel](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/aufsRootFileSystemOnUsbFlash) (Source: Ubuntu). You might be better off using [OverlayFS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/aufsRootFileSystemOnUsbFlash#Overlayfs), as suggested, the support of which apparently is already included.